# Is there a quick way to tell if a differential equation contradicts itself?

Tags: calculus, summation

If I have a differential equation of the form

$$\frac{d^2\vec{y_1}}{dx_1^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(\vec{y_1}-\vec{y_2}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}*\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}\right)}dx_2+\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(\vec{y_1}-\vec{y_1}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}*\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}\right)}dx_1$$

$$\frac{d^2\vec{y_2}}{dx_2^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(\vec{y_2}-\vec{y_1}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}*\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}\right)}dx_1+\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(\vec{y_2}-\vec{y_2}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}*\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}\right)}dx_2$$

and am given the values for $\vec{y_1}$, $\vec{y_2}$, $\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}$, and $\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}$ at $x_1=0$, and $x_2=0$

then thinking about the differential equation as

$$\lim_{\Delta{x_1},\Delta{{\vec{y_1}}}\rightarrow{0}}\frac{\Delta(\Delta{{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}})}{\Delta{x_1^2}}=\lim_{\Delta{x_2}\rightarrow{0}}\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2})}}{\Delta{x_2}}\right)*\Delta{x_2}\right)+\lim_{\Delta{x_1}\rightarrow{0}}\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1})}}{\Delta{x_1}}\right)*\Delta{x_1}\right)$$

$$\lim_{\Delta{x_2},\Delta{{\vec{y_2}}}\rightarrow{0}}\frac{\Delta(\Delta{{\vec{y_2}(x_2)}})}{\Delta{x_2^2}}=\lim_{\Delta{x_1}\rightarrow{0}}\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_2}(x_2)-\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2)}}{\Delta{x_2}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1})}}{\Delta{x_1}}\right)*\Delta{x_1}\right)+\lim_{\Delta{x_2}\rightarrow{0}}\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_2}(x_2)-\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2)}}{\Delta{x_2}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2})}}{\Delta{x_2}}\right)*\Delta{x_2}\right)$$

it looks like to find $\vec{y_1}(x_1+\Delta{x_1})$ I need to first have a value for $\frac{\Delta(\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)})}{\Delta{x_1^2}}$, but to have a value for $\frac{\Delta(\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)})}{\Delta{x_1^2}}$ I first need a value for

$$\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2})}}{\Delta{x_2}}\right)*\Delta{x_2}\right)+\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1})}}{\Delta{x_1}}\right)*\Delta{x_1}\right)$$

and to get a value for

$$\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_2}(x_2+n\Delta{x_2})}}{\Delta{x_2}}\right)*\Delta{x_2}\right)+\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\left(f\left(\vec{y_1}(x_1)-\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1}),\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1)}}{\Delta{x_1}}*\frac{\Delta{\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1})}}{\Delta{x_1}}\right)*\Delta{x_1}\right)$$

I first need a value for every $\vec{y_1}(x_1+n\Delta{x_1})$ including $\vec{y_1}(x_1+\Delta{x_1})$ meaning that this differential equation contains a circular reference, and I don't know if this circular reference means that for some functions

$$f\left(\vec{y_i}-\vec{y_j}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_i}}{dx_i}*\frac{d\vec{y_j}}{dx_j}\right)$$

the differential equation would be self contradictory.  I know in some special cases I could just use analytical solutions to tell that a given version of this differential equation is self consistent, but in the general case differential equations have no analytical solutions and I would think that even for most versions of my differential equation that are self consistent, a numerical approximation might be an NP problem.

So is there a quick way to tell if for a given
$f\left(\vec{y_i}-\vec{y_j}, 
\frac{d\vec{y_i}}{dx_i}*\frac{d\vec{y_j}}{dx_j}\right)$ and a set of initial values for $\vec{y_1}$, $\vec{y_2}$, $\frac{d\vec{y_1}}{dx_1}$, and $\frac{d\vec{y_2}}{dx_2}$ the differential equation is self contradictory without trying to solve it?

Comment: I know you want to avoid solving it in advance, but a way to go could be writing Newton Rhapson matrix for this system, and try to analyse its properties.

Comment: Your first equation is confusing because you're integrating with respect to $x$ (whereas we might expect $x$ and $y$ to appear free on the RHS). Which parts of the integrand vary as the integral is taken and which parts are fixed properties of the point at which we're computing $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Comment: @Karl Given any values for $y$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ $f\left(y,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ is fixed, as $f\left(y,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ is a function of $y$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$.  If allowing $y$ to vary given a value for $x$ would lead to a contradiction then $y$ is fixed for that value of $x$, but if allowing $y$ to vary given a value of $x$ does not lead to a contradiction then $y$ is allowed to vary for that value of $x$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still confused about what $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(y,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}dx$ is supposed to mean. Your second equation (with the limit) suggests you're interpreting it as $y''(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(y(x+t),y'(x+t))}dt$. But by the substitution $u=x+t$, this is equivalent to $y''(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(y(u),y'(u))}du$, so $y''(x)$ does not depend on $x$, i.e. $y''$ is constant. What am I missing?

Comment: I think I see how I added unnecessary confusion in my question as I used $dx$ and $\Delta{x}$ in the same equation, which I think makes it look like I mean two different things for $dx$ and $\Delta{x}$, when for numerical differentiation they aren't.  I found that it looks like I can change all my $d$s to $\Delta$s so I will do that and change the left hand side to be in terms of a double limit to make my second equation less confusing.  Let me know if you're still confused after that.

Comment: It still looks like your right-hand side is a constant function of $x$ since you're integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. This means $y''$ is constant, so $y$ is quadratic.

Comment: @Karl Originally I made my equation a simpler version of the type of equation I was thinking about.  I edited my post now to have the differential equation expanded out.